# get mongoConnection on beforeAll and AfterAll

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I want to get the MongoConnection before my tests and remove all collections after the test.
I create a file like test-setup.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.promise = global.Promise

async function removeAllCollections () {
  const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections)
  for (const collectionName of collections) {
    const collection = mongoose.connection.collections[collectionName]
    await collection.deleteMany()
  }
}

async function dropAllCollections () {
  
  const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections)
  for (const collectionName of collections) {
    const collection = mongoose.connection.collections[collectionName]
    console.log(collectionName)
    try {
      await collection.drop()
    } catch (error) {
      // Sometimes this error happens, but you can safely ignore it
      if (error.message === 'ns not found') return
      // This error occurs when you use it.todo. You can
      // safely ignore this error too
      if (error.message.includes('a background operation is currently running')) return
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
}

    module.exports = {
      setupDB (databaseName, runSaveMiddleware = false) {
        // Connect to Mongoose
        beforeAll(async () => {      
          const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDb'
          let conn = await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
          console.log(conn.collections)
        })
    
        // Seeds database before each test
        // beforeEach(async () => {
        //   await seedDatabase(runSaveMiddleware)
        // })
    
        // Cleans up database between each test
        afterEach(async () => {
          await removeAllCollections()
        })
    
        // Disconnect Mongoose
        afterAll(async () => {
          await dropAllCollections()
          await mongoose.connection.close()
        })
      }
    }
```

At the moment the seedDatabase is commented, but I'd like to create a database per each e2e files, but it's a second step.

So, I add this file to jest-e2e.json

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/test-setup.js"]
}
```

And on my test:

```
import * as request from 'supertest';
import {
  APP_URL,
  TESTER_EMAIL,
  TESTER_PASSWORD,
  MAIL_HOST,
  MAIL_PORT,
} from '../utils/constants';

describe('Auth user (e2e)', () => {
  const app = APP_URL;
  const mail = `http://${MAIL_HOST}:${MAIL_PORT}`;
  const newUserFirstName = `Tester${Date.now()}`;
  const newUsername = `E2E.${Date.now()}`;
  const newUserEmail = `User.${Date.now()}@example.com`;
  const newUserPassword = `secret`;
  const { setupDB } = require('../test-setup.js')

  setupDB('users', true)

  it('Login: /api/v1/auth/email/login (POST)', () => {
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/auth/email/login')
      .send({ email: TESTER_EMAIL, password: TESTER_PASSWORD })
      .expect(404)
      .expect(({ body }) => {        
        expect(404);
        expect(body.error).toBe('Not Found');
      });
  });

  it('Register new user: /api/v1/auth/email/register (POST)', async () => {
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/auth/email/register')
      .send({
        email: newUserEmail,
        password: newUserPassword,
        name: newUserFirstName,
        username: newUsername,
      })
      .expect(201);
  });
```

The test works, but still using the "main" database, the same database that I can find on app.module

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('database.url'),            
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
```

How can use the new database per each tests and delete the collections after the tests?
If I put console.log on my `test-setup.js` I can see the output.

UPDATE:
app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { MailModule } from './mail/mail.module';
import { I18nModule } from 'nestjs-i18n/dist/i18n.module';
import { I18nJsonParser } from 'nestjs-i18n/dist/parsers/i18n.json.parser';
import { HeaderResolver } from 'nestjs-i18n';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { MailConfigService } from './mail/mail-config.service';
import databaseConfig from './config/database.config';
import authConfig from './config/auth.config';
import appConfig from './config/app.config';
import mailConfig from './config/mail.config';

import * as path from 'path';
import { ForgotModule } from './forgot/forgot.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: ['.env', '.env.dev', '.env.stage', '.env.prod'],  //if a variable is found in multiple files, the first one takes precedence.
      load: [        
        databaseConfig,
        authConfig,
        appConfig,
        mailConfig,
      ],
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('database.url'),
        // useNewUrlParser: true,
        // useFindAndModify: false,
        // useCreateIndex: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MailConfigService,
    }),
    I18nModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        fallbackLanguage: configService.get('app.fallbackLanguage'),
        parserOptions: {
          path: path.join(
            configService.get('app.workingDirectory'),
            'src',
            'i18n',
            'translations',
          ),
        },
      }),
      parser: I18nJsonParser,
      inject: [ConfigService],
      resolvers: [new HeaderResolver(['x-custom-lang'])],
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    ForgotModule,    
    MailModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you show your `app.module`? And where is an application setup in your tests?

Comment: hello thanks for your time, I added my `app.module.ts`. unfortunately, I don't understand why the colors don't work on my snippet